# Name of permutation of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations, terminology

Let $M \in \Bbb R^n$ be a matrix and $\sigma \in S_n$ a permutation. Let $N$ be matrix such that $$N_{ij}=M_{\sigma(i)\sigma(j)}$$
For example if $$M=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}\text{ then } N=\begin{pmatrix} d & c \\ b & a\end{pmatrix}$$

I wanted to know if $N$ had a special name.

Comment: I don't think there's a special name. Looks to be just pre- and post-multiply by certain permutation matrices.

Comment: The relationship between $M$ and $N$ is called "permutation-similarity". In other words, $N$ is "permutation-similar" to $M$. There exists a permutation matrix $P$ such that $N = PMP^T$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \begin{pmatrix} d & c \\ b & a\end{pmatrix} = \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} \color{gray}{0} & 1 \\ 1 & \color{gray}{0} \end{pmatrix}}_{=: {\bf P}} \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \color{gray}{0} & 1 \\ 1 & \color{gray}{0} \end{pmatrix} $$

where $\bf P$ is the $2 \times 2$ [reversal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_matrix).